# Mean per group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a dot plot which is discrete in one direction and continuous in the other.  I then want to show the mean of each discrete value.

This is the closest I've got thus far:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars_with_brand <- mtcars %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  mutate(Brand = word(Car, 1,1, sep = " ")) %>%
  mutate(Brand = ifelse(Brand %in% c('Fiat','Toyota','Hornet', 'Merc'), Brand, 'zOther')) %>%
  mutate(Brand=reorder(Brand, mpg, mean))

mean_mpg <- mtcars_with_brand %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  mutate(mean_mpg = mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Brand, mean_mpg) %>%
  distinct()

mtcars_with_brand %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Brand, y = mpg)) +
  geom_col(data = mean_mpg, 
           aes(x = Brand,
               y = mean_mpg),
           col = "black",
           fill = "white") +
  geom_point(height = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(from=0.5, to=5.5, by=1), colour='#bbbbbb') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

But I would really prefer a single line at the y value, rather than the entire outline that the bar chart is giving me.

It feels like I'm trying to use the wrong geom for this, but I'm not sure what I should be doing instead.  I have looked into `geom_linerange` and similar, but if they were suitable to do this I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot both using `geom_point` and with the means derived using `group_by` and `summarise`. You seem to have a good grasp of the styling elements so I'll leave that out from here so the solution is clear:

```
ggplot() +
  # Points for each car
  geom_point(data = mtcars_with_brand, mapping = aes(y = Brand, x = mpg)) +
  # Vertical bars for the means
  geom_point(data = mtcars_with_brand %>% 
      # Group the data by brand then get means
      group_by(Brand) %>% 
      summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)), 
    # Specify aesthetics
    mapping = aes(y = Brand, x = mean_mpg), 
    size = 10, color = 'red', shape = '|')
```

[image]